# Using plural pronouns in a contract for a single entity

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

In regards to an NDA between a company and one person (employee or outside contractor), should the term "we" and "our" be used instead of "I" and "my"?

For example, here's a clause from my NDA:

*We* shall never, either during *our* dealings with COMPANY NAME or at any time after *our* relationship with COMPANY NAME ends, disclose any COMPANY NAME Proprietary Confidential Information to any third party...

Answer (score 1):

In English, individuals (in the first person) are "me/I" and "mine", individuals and groups (in the second person) are "you" and "your" and groups in the second person (which includes companies) are "we/us" and "our".

You should try to use whatever fits the situation. However, at law, unless the usage creates a real ambiguity, it doesn't matter if you get it wrong: the judge is not your English teacher.